# Sniffing packets using pcap header file, returned tcp header seems to be truncated or deformed

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, pcap

I am creating a small packet sniffer program and using pcap API to achieve this. At the moment I sniffing based on packets with source or destination ports 80 (http). Using the documentation - https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html, the returned packet is handled using the pcap_loop routine which takes in a session handler pointer,number of packets to sniff,a get_packet callback routine and additional arguments that can be set NULL.

pcap_loop(ppcap,-1,get_packet,NULL);

The interface that the packet sniffing is being ran on is wlp2s0. Towards the end of the documentation it states the structure of the packet containing:

Ethernet header (?? not sure why there is an ethernet header, because ethernet protocol is not being used)
IP header
TCP header
Payload
Within the get_packet routine which handles working with the incoming packets I have the following implementation:

```
void get_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,const u_char *packet){
        
        // packet structured in four layers 
    
        /*
            - Ethernet header 
            - ip header 
            - TCP header 
            - payload (containing data being transmitted)
    
            Each header is assumed to be in contigous memory position on the heap.
            
            ∴ 
            
            ethernet header pointer  = packet pointer
            ip header pointer = packet pointer  + ethernet header size
            TCP header pointer = packet pointer + ethernet header size + ip header size
    
            Each pointer is typecasted to its type
        */
    
        printf("GOT PACKET - %s\n\n",packet);
    
        ethernet = (const struct sniff_ethernet *)(packet); // typecasting packet pointer of type u_char to type const struct sniff_ip
    
        ip = (const struct sniff_ip * )(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET); // ip header which is located packet + eth address len (6 bytes), type casted to type const struct sniff_ip
       
        size_ip = IP_HL(ip) *4; // returns size of ip header
    
        if (size_ip < 20) {
            // triggered if ip header is less than 20 bytes
            return;
        }


tcp = (const struct sniff_tcp *) (packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip); // tcp header which is located packet + eth address len + ip address len (min 16 20 bytes)
    
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4; // returns size of tcp header length. return type unsigned int

    printf("TCP header is %d\n",size_tcp);
```

The returned TCP header by defination according to the documentation must be atleast 20 bytes but after running the program the TCP header returns 4 bytes. I do not know why the TCP header size seems to be truncated or deformed. I am new to networking but understand the very basics and believe this project can be a good springboard.